# Creating an array after concatenating selective array elements

Tags: ruby, erb

I'm woring on a .ERB template (for puppet) with a text file like this:

```
ec2-23-22-59-32, mongoc, i-b8b44, instnum=0, Running
ec2-54-27-11-46, mongod, i-43f9f, instnum=1, Running
...
...
ec2-78-62-92-20, mongod, i-02fa4, instnum=8, Running
ec2-24-47-51-23, mongos, i-546c4, instnum=9, Running
```

and I'm trying to get an array like this out of it:

```
['mongoc-i-b8b44', 'mongod-i-43f9f', .... 'mongod-i-02fa4', 'mongos-i-546c4']
```

I can do a few things, like create an array taking only the 2nd and 3rd elements:

```
a_type = []
IO.foreach(inFile) do |line|
  a_type.push line.split(',')[1..2].map(&:strip)
end
a_type.join(',')
# => mongoc,i-b5b406dd,mongod,i-b6f9f1d5
```

or join the all the array elements like this:

```
ar = ['sd', 'ser', 'wer']
ar.map! { |k| "#{k}" }.join('-')
# => "sd-ser-wer"
```

but can't figure out how to achieve the result that I'm looking for. Any help/pointer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
File.read(inFile).each_line.map do |line|
  line.split(', ')[1..2].join('-')
end
```

Comment: I'd write: `open(inFile).lines.map`

Comment: @Amit: Spot on! Didn't realize it's gonna be that simple; I was thinking rocket science. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @tokland: Could you explain what's the (functional) difference between `each_line.map` and `lines.map`?

Comment: `File.read` reads the whole file in memory. `open(path).lines` reads the file line by line, lazily. Unnoticeable for small files, useful for big files, a must for really large files.